# Java problem on AIX 6.1 - Processing dump event "gpf", detail ""

Tags: java, aix, documentum

I have problem with EMC's Documentum Java on AIX 6.1 server. I have install it in /dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/. For example when I run command "java -version" from /dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/bin, I get this error:

```
dmadmin@czprguxdv23$ java -version
Unhandled exception
Type=Illegal instruction vmState=0x00040000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000010 Signal_Number=00000004 Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=0000001e
Handler1=F0460038 Handler2=F0457A98
R0=00000000 R1=301117F0 R2=00000000 R3=30111830
R4=00000000 R5=D24E5888 R6=F04F0B20 R7=00000190
R8=7869F2D8 R9=BD00C028 R10=00000001 R11=00000000
R12=D24D0B70 R13=30CEE500 R14=30D5D170 R15=F062C220
R16=00000007 R17=00000000 R18=F0462198 R19=30CEE550
R20=3208D280 R21=30D5D190 R22=00000000 R23=30000B40
R24=10010DA4 R25=F0458BE0 R26=30117594 R27=0000012F
R28=B0059350 R29=00000004 R30=D24E51A8 R31=F04EEDF8
IAR=00000000 LR=D24D0B90 MSR=0000D032 CTR=00000000
CR=29000350 FPSCR=82020000 XER=00000006 TID=00000000
MQ=00000000
FPR0 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR1 41e0000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 2.147484e+09)
FPR2 c1e0000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: -2.147484e+09)
FPR3 3fe8000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 7.500000e-01)
FPR4 4047800000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 4.700000e+01)
FPR5 4330080000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 4.512396e+15)
FPR6 3fd6666666666666 (f: 1717986944.000000, d: 3.500000e-01)
FPR7 3ff0000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 1.000000e+00)
FPR8 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR9 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR10 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR11 4026000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 1.100000e+01)
FPR12 3fe8000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 7.500000e-01)
FPR13 4020800000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 8.250000e+00)
FPR14 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR15 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR16 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR17 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR18 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR19 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR20 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR21 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR22 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR23 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR24 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR25 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR26 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR27 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR28 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR29 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR30 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
FPR31 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
Target=2_40_20090923_042924 (AIX 6.1)
CPU=ppc (4 logical CPUs) (0x170000000 RAM)
Stack Backtrace /dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/lib/ppc/libzip.so:0xD24FB0FC 0xD24EE000 +0x0000D0FC
/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/lib/ppc/libzip.so:0xD24FBBB0 0xD24EE000 +0x0000DBB0
/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/lib/ppc/libzip.so:0xD24F9698 0xD24EE000 +0x0000B698
/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/lib/ppc/libj9vm24.so:0xD10323E4 0xD0FEA000 +0x000483E4
/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/lib/ppc/libjclscar_24.so:0xD2466474 0xD2455000 +0x00011474
/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/lib/ppc/libj9vm24.so:0xD1053608 0xD0FEA000 +0x00069608
/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/lib/ppc/libj9vm24.so:0xD0FFC6D4 0xD0FEA000 +0x000126D4
/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/lib/ppc/libj9vm24.so:0xD0FFC940 0xD0FEA000 +0x00012940
/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/lib/ppc/libj9prt24.so:0xD106C828 0xD1069000 +0x00003828
/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/lib/ppc/libj9vm24.so:0xD0FFC7F4 0xD0FEA000 +0x000127F4
/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/lib/ppc/libj9vm24.so:0xD0FFC784 0xD0FEA000 +0x00012784
java:0x10001D20 0x10000000 +0x00001D20
java:0x10001564 0x10000000 +0x00001564
/usr/lib/libpthreads.a:0xD04DEC50 0xD04DB000 +0x00003C50
0x00000000
JVMDUMP006I Processing dump event "gpf", detail "" - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/bin/core.20110505.101207.7012530.0001.dmp' in response to an event
Note: "Enable full CORE dump" in smit is set to FALSE and as a result there will be limited threading information in core file.
JVMDUMP010I System dump written to /dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/bin/core.20110505.101207.7012530.0001.dmp
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/bin/Snap.20110505.101207.7012530.0002.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/bin/Snap.20110505.101207.7012530.0002.trc
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/bin/javacore.20110505.101207.7012530.0003.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /dctm/dfc_shared/java/1.6.0_00/jre/bin/javacore.20110505.101207.7012530.0003.txt
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "gpf", detail "".
```

Have you any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks,
Michell

Comment: This was one of pair cluster servers. On the second server java runs without any problems.  So I replaced broken /dctm/dfc_shared/java by java from second server. Now it runs well.

Answer (score 0):

This was one of pair cluster servers. 
On the second server java runs without any problems.

So I replaced broken /dctm/dfc_shared/java by java from second server. Now it runs well.

```
dmadmin@czprguxdv23$ java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap3260sr6-20090925_01(SR6))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc-32 jvmap3260sr6-20090923_42924 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20090923_042924
JIT  - r9_20090902_1330ifx1
GC   - 20090817_AA)
JCL  - 20090924_01
```

Michell